# Python discord.py: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord-api

Я написал код с видео, и у него на видео всё работает, но я не понимаю, в чём ошибка.

Код:

```
import discord


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))


client = MyClient()
client.run("MTA1MTE4MDY0MzUzNjYyMTYxOQ.GFICXi.tWMh_gjaQndwe7wG0mVuSKmW0J_4Gtdzdq6iKw")
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
File "C:\Users\hadji\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dsrolebot\rolebot.py", line 10, in <module>
    client = MyClient()
TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать значение по умолчанию Intents, если у вас нет конкретного для указания

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

Comment: я писал вместо client = Myclient, client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default()) суть бота то что он пишет все сообщения с сервера дискорд но он этого не делал и написало при запуске 2022-12-10 21:40:19 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2022-12-10 21:40:22 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: b4a1f1b926c7517bc0d666143d9953f1).

Answer (score 0):

Выше правильно сказали. у меня была такая же проблема, я записала вместо "client = Myclient" код ниже + запускала через терминал не cmd, а VSC:

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Пишу для тех, кто тоже запутался и код не работает, как на видео